# Isn't 埋 the Private Polar Antonym of 埋怨?

Tags: etymology

If you're complaining or grumbling (埋怨), then undeniably you're NOT burying or concealing (埋) your grievance or complaint! So why does 埋 belong in 埋怨? Doesn't 埋 gainsay 埋怨?

[image]

*Oxford Chinese Dictionary* (2010) p 482.

[image]

[*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary), p 599.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the difference in pronunciation: in 埋怨 the character 埋 is read `mán` and not `mái`.

*Outlier*

> mán
> ○ to blame, complain

Here the ○ icon is an indicator of a [phonetic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters). So, basically it is just a:

> character that is "borrowed" to write another homophonous or near-homophonous morpheme

Answer (score 0):

埋 - Lay

怨 - Blame

埋怨 - Lay blame on (place one's feeling of resentment on someone, or something).

"埋" 是一個破音字在此唸"ㄇㄢˊ(注音)" "mán(拼音)"